# Fix WoeUSB installation issue

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, 20.04, woeusb

I have added the PPA to install WoeUSB on Ubuntu 20.04.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`

Then I tried to install WoeUSB.

```
martin@slazer:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install woeusb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 woeusb : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

There was a missing package so I searched for it and installed it.

```
martin@slazer:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-cache search libwxgtk3.0
libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 runtime)
libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev - wxWidgets Cross-platform C++ GUI toolkit (GTK 3 development)
```

However, the same error persists. I think it's just a labeling issue since `libwxgtk3.0-0v5` and `libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5` are very similar. If it is so, is it possible to somehow trick Ubuntu to recognize the package under different name - perhaps using symbolic links?

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: So now that Ubuntu 20.04 has been released for the past few months, how have people fixed this issue?